# touchBegan, check if touching a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I have a number of CAShapeLayers being drawn and in my touchesBegan function I would like to perform an action when one of these layers has been touched.

One of my methods drawing a layer:

```
func drawBoundary(line: UIBezierPath) {
    let boundaryLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    boundaryLayer.lineCap = .square
    boundaryLayer.path = line.cgPath
    boundaryLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    boundaryLayer.lineWidth = 100
    boundaryLayer.opacity = 0.2
    boundaryLayer.accessibilityLabel = "OuterBoundary"

    self.layer.addSublayer(boundaryLayer)
}
```

touchedBegan function:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let point = touch!.location(in: self)
    print(point)

    if let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers as? [CAShapeLayer]
    {
        for layer in sublayers
        {
            if layer.path!.contains(point)
            {
                print("In boundary")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

However, I get no response when I tap within the drawn shapes, the layers are printing to the screen and if I loop through the layers and print to console each layer is printing. Just not sure how to properly pick up that I have touched them.

This is how my shapes are printing, the green shaded area is the result of drawBoundary() and the grey circles are being drawn in the same way in another method:

[image]

I have a feeling it is picking up these layers as CALayers instead of CAShapeLayer which has no .path value

Comment: I think you should do if let inside the for loop, not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast self.layer.sublayers to an array of [CAShapeLayer] which will not likely happen. You need to check if each element in self.layer.sublayers is a CAShapeLayer. Try this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let point = touch!.location(in: self)

    guard let sublayers = layer.sublayers else { return }

    for sublayer in sublayers {
        if let sublayer = sublayer as? CAShapeLayer, let path = sublayer.path {
            if path.contains(point) {
                print("yes")
            }
        }
    }
}
```